# Is there a way to run selenium within visual studio as a different user?

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently when I run visual studio it runs as my admin account. My admin account does not have access to run google chrome so when I try running a selenium test case locally it does not work. I was wondering if it possible within visual studio to start up selenium as my non admin user and therefore run google chrome with selenium with my non admin credentials. FYI I have extensively googled this and found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: I would guess you could do [impersonation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8) in code to run that piece of code as another user. But it seems weird to me that an admin account don't have access to run google chrome. Have you tried running Visual Studio as elevated? (right click on Visual Studio an select `Run as Administrator`

Comment: @Michael so the problem is at my current organization we are only to run visual studio as an admin but we don't want to allow chrome to be ran as our admin user. Therefore we are trying to find a way to launch chrome as our non admin account from within visual studio. I have successfully impersonated myself as my non admin account in visual studio but it still launches chrome from my admin account :/

See the following link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798842/how-to-get-simpleimpersonation-library-to-open-chrome-as-a-different-user